# Kafka consumer query

Tags: apache-kafka

To launch a Kafka consumer I have to run it with the following params.

`kafka-console-consumer.bat --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic MyTopic`

Was wondering why it needs to have a zookeeper as a param, if I use the broker param will it not work similar to how the producer is launched. Consumer needs to be aware of the broker/cluster and not the zookeeper location.

`.\kafka-console-producer.bat --broker --list localhost:9092 --topic MyTopic`

This is on windows, am not sure how its in Unix flavors.

-Chandra

Answer (score 1):

You're invoking the old Kafka Consumer. Old consumer requires zookeeper to co-ordinate from which broker to fetch data.

The new consumer don't requires the zookeeper parameter.

```
.\kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic MyTopic --new-consumer
```

Optionally, you can add `--from-beginning` argument to read the old records in the topic.